# Angular ng-click is not working when using DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

i have created `<img>` run time from my controller and i have used `ngSanitize` for compile my html as trusted html

code is :

```
$scope.renderImageHtml = function(html_code) {
  var finalHtml = "" + $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
  finalHtml = finalHtml.replace(/<img/g, "<img data-ng-click=\"fullScreenImage()\" ");
  return $sce.trustAsHtml(finalHtml);
};

$scope.fullScreenImage = function() {
  console.log("fullScreenImage");
}
```

after comple html code lookes like :

```
<img data-ng-click="fullScreenImage()"  
 alt="" src="http://192.168.0.16/userfiles/image/EMI1.png"  
 style="width: 200px; height: 99px;">
```

html is proper but click event is not working

Comment: yes but you are not passing anything in `$scope.fullScreenImage` function,

Comment: in what way it is not working?

Comment: when i clicking on image click event is not executing @JanLeeYu

Comment: i am printing in log not doing any thing @ojuskulkarni

Comment: you see this `<img data-ng-click="fullScreenImage()..."` when you inspect the elements?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile your HTML using `$compile`.Also inject $compile a dependency in your controller.

```
$scope.renderImageHtml = function(html_code){
 var finalHtml =  "" + $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code) ;
 finalHtml = finalHtml.replace(/<img/g,"<img data-ng-click=\"fullScreenImage()\" ");
$compile(finalHtml)($scope);
 return $sce.trustAsHtml(finalHtml);
};
```

Comment: its not working giving error in log :
ionic.bundle.js:26794 Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!

Comment: Basically you need to re compile your html. Try with alternative.

Comment: `$sce.trustAsHtml` will compile html